# how to skip / ignore skip null byte in csv file using pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, null

I have a .csv file that has hundreds of lines/columns that look like this (small example, see image I couldnt copy/paste the null bytes had to type them manually):[image]

```
9142,16.04000000,14.65000000
<0x00><0x00><0x00>
9143,16.19000000,14.65000000
```

there are a small number of lines that contain NULL bytes ("<0x00>") that are giving me trouble when trying to read the csv using pandas pd.read_csv.

when I run the command :

```
pd.read_csv(fname, header=None, na_values='-32768', names=binnams, engine='python')
```

I get the following error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: ("NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass in engine='c' instead", 'occurred at index 16')
```

and when I switch the engine='c' I get:

```
TypeError: ('cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object', 'occurred at index 16')
```

Is there a way to ignore these lines completely using pd.read_csv?

I think a workaround might be to open the files and loop through them and delete any lines that contain the <0x00> if it can even be read?

Any thoughts/suggestions are definitely appreciated.

EDIT - tried to read the files line by line to see if I could delete these lines but not sure how to actually capture the null byte (using "<0x00>" obv didn't work :D )

link to example file here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uEjMv0Be9Hu_AqXRzqB3enrWilzCTBvc

Comment: I tried using Jupyter notebook and it works with me. Are you using Jupyter or something else? I added the following to the csv file : 9142,16.04000000,14.65000000
<0x00><0x00><0x00>
9143,16.19000000,14.65000000

Comment: Some other suggestions are to use encoding : pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, na_values='-32768', engine='python',encoding = "utf-8"). Maybe you need to change utf-8, depend on what you have.

Comment: I think the issue is the <0x00> is not a string .. it's actually a null byte in the file, when you paste my example it's just like putting a string in  ..  I couldn't even copy/paste the null bytes into the OP I had to type them manually

Comment: Also, not using Jupyter. Just python shell right now (3.7.3)

Comment: example file posted in edit

Comment: There are many dialects of csv, the null bytes could be used to represent empty columns or for padding. Python's csv library supports many dialects. If your's isn't supported, you need to write a custom parser. That shouldn't be too hard if you know for what the null bytes stand for.

Comment: I tried to save the csv file you sent as UTF-16, then it works!

Comment: thanks.. I saved it at utf-16 and modified the code to:

pd.read_csv('file.TXT',header=None,na_values='-32768',engine='c',encoding='utf-16',error_bad_lines=False)

and it worked...much appreciated...

Comment: @DerekEden, I added it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save the csv file as UTF-16 then try to run code:

```
pd.read_csv(fname, header=None, na_values='-32768', names=binnams, engine='python')
```

Comment: I saved it at utf-16 and modified the code to: pd.read_csv('file.TXT',header=None,na_values='-32768',names=binnams, engine='c',encoding='utf-16',error_bad_lines=False) and it worked...much appreciated...